# OCR cleaning data by merging two strings of same data

Tags: validation, ocr

I am building an app that uses OCR using the google cloud api. I want to improve the accuracy of the text sent back to me by having using scan the document twice and then merging those two scans.

I have say these two sentences after two scans "Hel how re you" and "Helloh ow are yo" How can I merge these two strings in order to get something like "Hello how are you"

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a cloud based API? This might be a bad user experience as sending data back and forth to the server takes time. How about a mobile OCR which scans everything in under a second? Tesseract is one such free library. There are commercial ones.